# Google Docs' PDF viewer

Tags: fonts, viewers, latin-modern, computer-modern

I downloaded the `cm-super` package and for comparison, created 5 versions of my document with different fonts:

- Computer Modern
- CM-Super
- CM-Super with `microtype`
- Latin Modern
- Latin Modern with `microtype`

All 5 versions were then uploaded to Google Docs and viewed with their PDF viewer which AFAIK generates PNG images for the browser to display.

Here is an image showing a portion with Computer Modern:
[image]

This is Latin Modern with `microtype`:
[image]

As you can see Latin Modern was rendered into an ugly duckling. The same happened to CM-Super too. Disturbing about this is that CM-Super and Latin Modern look much better in Adobe Reader than CM, so it seems I have to decide between online and offline viewing.

My question is:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I disable `cm-super` in MiKTeX if I decide upon using the original CM font? Is uninstalling in Package Manager the only way (and does it work)?
   (Sorry for so distant questions.)

**EDIT:** MWE
Unfortunately you can't switch `cm-super` on and off so simply.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
A természettudományok az általuk vizsgált jelenségeket gyakran differenciálegyenlet-rendszerrel írják le. Ekkor fontos szemponttá válik annak eldöntése, hogy az adott rendszer stabil-e. A stabilitás hozzávetőlegesen azt jelenti, hogy a külső körülmények (kezdeti feltételek) piciny megváltoztatása nem okozza a rendszer működésének (a megoldásnak) radikális megváltozását.
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:** It seems that Google Docs' problem is with vectorized fonts in general. The non-T1 encoded original CM fonts also looked ugly. (The T1 encoded CM fonts are raster fonts.)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18519/627

Comment: Is it possible that Google Docs is screwing up the rendering?

Comment: Add `\pdfmapfile{}` at the beginning of your document and *no* map file will be read in. If the document uses only CM (or, more precisely, European Modern, as you're using T1 encoding), the bitmap versions will be created and used. It's not difficult to create a new map file that doesn't use the CM-Super fonts.

Comment: @percusse That's for sure.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, that worked! Is that safe?

Comment: What version of LaTeX did you compile with? PDFTeX? LuaTeX? Does it change if you use the other?

Comment: @Canageek I use PDFTeX. I don't know how to use LuaTex.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think that making one's PDF worse just because a bad previewer isn't able to render it is the right answer. If a previewer is bad, I simply don't use it.

However, it's not difficult to prepare a personal map file that doesn't use the CM-Super fonts.

1. Copy `pdftex.map` in a working directory, renaming it to, say, `pdftex-nosuper.map`; you find the location of `pdftex.map` by looking in any log file created by `pdflatex`, but on a Unix system (and `bash`), just

   ```bsh
   cp $(kpsewhich pdftex.map) .
   ```

   will do.
2. Open the file in a text editor
3. Remove all lines where the string `cm-super` appears (a Perl or `sed` script can do it automatically)
4. Save the file and put a copy of it in your personal tree; on a GNU/Linux system this should be in `~/texmf`

   ```bsh
   mkdir -p ~/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex
   cp pdftex-nosuper.map ~/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/
   ```
5. Put the line

   ```
   \pdfmapfile{pdftex-nosuper.map}
   ```

   at the start of your LaTeX document.

When `pdftex` will process your document, bitmaps for the fonts covered by the CM-Super fonts will be created and downloaded in the PDF output.

Note: if you're using MacTeX on Mac OS X, then instead of the `~/texmf` prefix, use `~/Library/texmf`. With TeX Live on Windows, the commands for creating the directory and doing copies of files will be different. For the correct location with MiKTeX, consult the documentation.